# Move rectangle on canvas on a custom pixel grid

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, label

I wrote this piece of code for practicing, it moves my labels while the left mouse button pushed:

```
def motion(self, event):
    delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]

    self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)

    self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
```

Next i try to move the labels on a defined grid of lets say 5 pixels. So it is easier to "snap" the labels directly together.

How do i do this? Is there a way to move the label only every 5 pixels? So every 5 pixels the label jumps under the cursor again.

Here is the example i found where i extracted the function:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")

        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we set deltas of x and y to 5 and then check whether mouse position is behind/under our item and if it is we multiply x or y it by -1 to make delta negative so our item will move in direction of our mouse.

```
def motion(self, event):
    delta_x = 0
    delta_y = 0
    step = 5

    if abs(event.x - self._drag_data["x"]) >= step:
        delta_x = step
    if abs(event.y - self._drag_data["y"]) >= step:
        delta_y = step

    if event.x < self._drag_data["x"]:
        delta_x *= -1
    if event.y < self._drag_data["y"]:
        delta_y *= -1

    self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)

    if delta_x != 0:
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    if delta_y != 0:
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
```

Comment: It does what i was asking for. I just forgot to write it should move in sync with the cursor. Sorry for that! I move the mouse like 4 pixels nothing happens. if i move it 5 pixels the label should snap to the next 5 pixel grid.

Comment: Updated, try it now.

Comment: Now i got some weird movement, sometimes the label moves with the mouse but off target. Sometimes nothing happes.

Comment: Could you supply enough code that's needed to recreate this problem?

Comment: Added it to my post!

Comment: Problem was that we were updating our `_drag_data` even if we didn't actually moved our canvas, updating answer with that bug fixed.

Comment: Working fine until i move the cursor diagonal. Then the label is off target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184108/discussion-between-filip-mlynarski-and-k-doe).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply round the `delta_x` and `delta_y` to the closest multiple of the step size:

```
def on_token_motion(self, event):
    step = 20

    # Calculate drag distance
    delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]

    # Round to nearest multiple of step size
    delta_x = int(step * round(float(delta_x)/step))
    delta_y = int(step * round(float(delta_y)/step))

    # Move the object
    self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)

    # Update _drag_data to the new position
    self._drag_data["x"] = self._drag_data["x"] + delta_x
    self._drag_data["y"] = self._drag_data["y"] + delta_y
```

Note that I also changed the `_drag_data` update. The new position of the object is not equal to `event.x` anymore, since we snap to the grid. Therefore, we must update it as `self._drag_data["x"] + delta_x`, which is the old position plus the amount moved.